# Copy file to debug folder

Tags: c#, sqlite

I programed an application that should copy file of database (bazarganidb.db) from driver d into debug folder.if i want copy this into some another location it has not any problem but when i do it for debug folder nothing happen, no file will be delete or copy.whats my wrong?
its my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string OriginalFile = @"D:\bazarganidb.db";
        string FileToReplace = @"E:\BazarganiProj2\BazarganiProj\bin\Debug\bazarganidb.db";

        if(File.Exists(FileToReplace))
            File.Delete(FileToReplace);
        File.Copy(OriginalFile, FileToReplace);
    }
    catch (Exception k)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Is that folder's property set to read only?

Comment: It would also help if you explained [what you hope to accomplish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) by doing this. Copying files into your project debug folder is very problematic.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bad practice to hard code the path, use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to reference the path:

```
  string FileToReplace = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), "bazarganidb.db");
```

also check your permissions to that folder, try to create file or folder manually and it will indicate if you have a permission block.

also, if you want to override the file, use the designate constructor with the 3 arguments, the third argument must be set to true if you want to override the existing file:

```
File.Copy(OriginalFile, FileToReplace,true);
```

Comment: excuse me but it didn,t solved my problem.I removed read only from debug folder and changed code to  your suggest but it didnt solved

Comment: just to make sure, the path of your project is on your local pc? (i mean not on local network) and what is the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: its in drive E.I dont have eny exception but i have no change in my file.I just want copy a file into the debug folder of my project at runtime

Comment: change the line  `File.Copy(OriginalFile, FileToReplace);` to  `File.Copy(OriginalFile, FileToReplace,true);` now what happens?

Comment: it didnt changed but i found that when i remove read only from my project and then press apply and ok when i back to properties of project its still read only but i dont know why

Comment: You are not admin on this user, try to open visual studio as adminstrator, right click "open as administrator", open your project and run.

Comment: unfortunatly it didn't solve my problem i run as administrator but no change.... @jonathana

Comment: what directory do you get when you `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(FileToReplace)` ?